# Webpage automatically scrolling to top while scrolling down on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website is working fine on desktop screen or the screen size larger than 1024px width. But it's having a scrolling problem while loading the website on the screen size less than 1024px.

The page automatically scrolls to top while scrolling down.

Link: [http://www.thevishalmehra.rf.gd/](http://thevishalmehra.rf.gd)

Comment: Show the code, what you have attempted to do and specify what is not working as you want it to.

Comment: It's because the objects that shows only when it comes into view, these objects expands the containers' sizes, making it shows like the website is scrolling up. One possible - not very good - fix, is to pre locate the containers sizes.

Comment: how to pre locate container sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/scrollspy/

"When using scrollspy in conjunction with adding or removing of elements from the DOM, you’ll need to call the refresh method like so:"

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
  var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
})
```

Try this:

```
<li class="timeline-item scroll-animations" data-spy="scroll">
  ...
</li>
```

Comment: You need put the attribute data-spy="scroll" in all elements what apper during scrolling.